# Did Boeing subcontract the manufacturing of the wings on the B757 series?

Tags: boeing, aircraft-manufacturer, boeing-757

If Boeing did subcontract, which company took over the manufacturing of the wings? Where were the wings made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 757 Wings and Wing & Center Body Section was manufactured at the Renton plant at KRNT.

Comment: Is the "Center Body" not the fuselage?

Comment: @AirbusLover I think the Center Body means the middle part of the fuselage...

Comment: @AnandS oh, ok. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Winging center body is a section of the fuselage, which contains a structural members that the wings attached to. That is Boeing’s particular way to manufacture an airliner.